# Save like button action in cache

Tags: android, sqlite, button, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener

I've created an app that a users can like each post. Like Samsung music:

[image]

and I used onclicklistener on imageview with a boolean condition to like or unlike it.

I want to save like action after pushing it in app cache like sharedprefences or sqlite or ... .
I know I can do this with id of users in server, But in my app users are not registered and can use it without registration. So I want save this action to cache.
If It is possible, please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, it will be better with a custom checkbox.

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/likeIcon"
style="@style/ThumbIconStyle"
android:background="@drawable/selector_like"
android:stateListAnimator="@animator/scale" />
```

With the background is an selector state for checked and unchecked.
And animator/scale is a animator state list.

Comment: Thanks, But CheckBox also cannot hold when you finish a activity, am I right?
I want to keep it in the cache.